# While using P/Invoke for c to c# and mashalling c struct to c# generates AccessViolationException, what could be the reason?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

I have to use a c++ dll in my project with P/Invoke i'm calling a function which involves a struct as well, which is generate AccessViolationException.

The specifics are below: following is the c++ function.

```
Int BII_Read_Transaction_Log_Ex(int iOption, int iUpdateFlag, int *iMaxEntries, BII_Transaction_Log_Ex *log)
```

Here is my method declaration.

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bioscrypt\SecureSDK\DLL\BII_V1100.dll", EntryPoint = "BII_Read_Transaction_Log_Ex")]
public unsafe static extern int GetTransactionLogs(int option, int updateFlag, ref int maxEnteries, ref BII_Transaction_Log_Ex[] transactionLogs);
```

It involves following struct.

```
typedef struct
{
unsigned int id; // ID of the template whose action was recorded
unsigned char reserved_1;
unsigned char index; // Index of the template whose action was recorded
unsigned short year; // Years since 2002 action was recorded
unsigned char month; // Months since January action was recorded (0-11) unsigned char
unsigned char day; // Day of month action was recorded (1-31)
unsigned char hour; // Hour (0-23), Minute and Second (0-59) – Time of action
unsigned char min;
unsigned char sec;
unsigned char trans_code; // Trans_code, Data1, Data2, Data3 – See table below
unsigned char flag_port; //Bit 5. Bit 6 Bit 7 unused Bit 0-4: port (0 – host, 1 – aux, 3–Wiegand, 5 – GPI0, 6 – GPI1, 8 – Search)
unsigned char trans_log_data_1;
unsigned char trans_log_data_2;
unsigned char trans_log_data_3;
unsigned char reserved_2;
unsigned char status; //0 if action failed, 1 if action succeeded
char name[16]; // Name field of Template for which log is stored
unsigned short duration; // Enroll / Verify duration in milliseconds
unsigned short template_size; // Size of template in bytes for which log is stored
signed short error_code; // Error code if enroll / verify failed
unsigned char sensor_type; // Sensor type connected to device
unsigned char unit_id; // Unit ID assigned to device, same as net ID (Get/Set command for net ID BII_GET_NETID / BII_SET_NETID)
unsigned char admin_level; // Admin level of template for which log is stored
unsigned char rsz_3; /* Reserved */
unsigned char rsz_4; /* Reserved */
unsigned char rsz_5; /* Reserved */
char ta_msg[16]; /*F1,F2,F3,F4 key message */
}BII_Transaction_Log_Ex;
```

My implemenation of this struct in c# is following.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
   public struct BII_Transaction_Log_Ex
   {
     public  UInt32 id; // ID of the template whose action was recorded
     public  Byte reserved_1;
     public  Byte index; // Index of the template whose action was recorded
     public  UInt16 year; // Years since 2002 action was recorded
     public  Byte month; // Months since January action was recorded (0-11) unsigned char
     public  Byte day; // Day of month action was recorded (1-31)
     public  Byte hour; // Hour (0-23), Minute and Second (0-59) – Time of action
     public  Byte min;
     public  Byte sec;
     public  Byte trans_code; // Trans_code, Data1, Data2, Data3 – See table below
     public  Byte flag_port; //Bit 5. Bit 6 Bit 7 unused Bit 0-4: port (0 – host, 1 – aux, 3– Wiegand, 5 – GPI0, 6 – GPI1, 8 – Search)
     public  Byte trans_log_data_1;
     public  Byte trans_log_data_2;
     public  Byte trans_log_data_3;
     public  Byte reserved_2;
     public  Byte status; //0 if action failed, 1 if action succeeded
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
     public  byte[] name; //char name[16]; // Name field of Template for which log is stored
     public  UInt16 duration; // Enroll / Verify duration in milliseconds
     public  UInt16 template_size; // Size of template in bytes for which log is stored
     public  SByte error_code; // Error code if enroll / verify failed
     public  Byte sensor_type; // Sensor type connected to device
     public  Byte unit_id; // Unit ID assigned to device, same as net ID (Get/Set command for net ID BII_GET_NETID / BII_SET_NETID)
     public  Byte admin_level; // Admin level of template for which log is stored
     public  Byte rsz_3; /* Reserved */
     public  Byte rsz_4; /* Reserved */
     public  Byte rsz_5; /* Reserved */
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
     public  byte[] ta_msg; /*F1,F2,F3,F4 key message */
   }
```

Now when i call the function using, it generates the AccessViolationException and shows following message: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

```
    int transactionsCount=-1;
    BII_Transaction_Log_Ex[] logs = new BII_Transaction_Log_Ex[1000];
    int result = GetTransactionLogs(0, 0, ref transactionsCount, ref logs);
```

I think that i'm making some mistak in marshelling the struct involved, but so far i'm unable find out the exact problem. Any help would be appreciated..

Edit: I don't have c++ source code.

Comment: Can you do a sizeof in C++ and one in C# to compare both structure? (make sure it map over each other correctly)

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks for the suggestion, Unfortunately I don't have c++ code, it's just a dll. I believe i cannot do sizeof without it.

Comment: `ref BII_Transaction_Log_Ex[]` is equal to `BII_Transaction_Log_Ex**`, C++ function receives pointer to pointer. To write correct PInvoke code, you need C++ code which calls this function. C++ function prototype is not enough.

Comment: @AlexFarber Thanks alot for you comment, i made changes based on your tip and it worked.. :)

Comment: What made you set `Pack=1`? And of course you can do sizeof for both sides. You certainly do have C++ code. You pasted it into the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ function is declared like so:

```
int BII_Read_Transaction_Log_Ex(
    int iOption, 
    int iUpdateFlag, 
    int *iMaxEntries, 
    BII_Transaction_Log_Ex *log
);
```

The final parameter could be a single struct, passed by reference. In which case the C# would be:

```
[DllImport(@"...", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "BII_Read_Transaction_Log_Ex")]
public static extern int GetTransactionLogs(
    int option, 
    int updateFlag, 
    ref int maxEntries, 
    ref BII_Transaction_Log_Ex transactionLogs
);
```

Note that there is no need for unsafe here, so I removed it. And it looks very much like the C++ function uses `cdecl`.

However, the use of the plural in `transactionLogs`, and the `maxEntries` parameter makes me suspect that the C++ code expects an array. In which case you write:

```
[DllImport(@"...", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl,
    EntryPoint = "BII_Read_Transaction_Log_Ex")]
public static extern int GetTransactionLogs(
    int option, 
    int updateFlag, 
    ref int maxEntries, 
    [Out] BII_Transaction_Log_Ex[] transactionLogs
);
```

I'm also somewhat sceptical of your use of `Pack=1` in the struct definition. What made you do that. I would expect an aligned struct in which case you should remove `Pack`. I don't think it matters since the C++ struct puts reserved members in the spaces where padding would be added, but I'd still rather see the struct declared as aligned.